# iOS Interface Builder Custom Styles?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, themes, styles

Simple question. Does anyone know why Interface Builder doesn't allow for applying custom styles on UI elements? Why is it only possible to do this programmatically?

I can see how this might be difficult for custom UIView subclasses but the default controls definitely only have a tiny subset of the style options available through IB, such as background color or changing font colors. Why is this the case? Is there any way to approach a concept like application themes through IB?

Comment: Favorite and Vote + because I am interested if anyone else has other opinions or experiences.

Comment: Hey, I was looking to do the exact same thing—define my own style set and have IB pull from it in real-time—and think I found a good solution. I put together a guide at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682764/accessing-text-styles-in-interface-builder-and-or-storyboards.

Answer (score 4):

My personal feeling is that Apple does this right. They provide the elements and styles that fit the HIG. If they start adding other elements/styles then where do the start, and where do they draw the line?

Also, it isn't like Apple actively prevents using custom elements/styles, they just don't include it in the tool set.

The last thing we need is a tool set full of bloat.

Answer (score 3):

You'd really have to ask Apple as to the *why*. I'd *guess* that it's some combination of promoting consistent use of standard interface elements and limited development resources.

You can, of course, build interfaces using your own custom subclasses of the standard interface elements in IB. It's a little more work, since you have to change the type of each object you add from UIButton to MyGreenButton or whatever, but it's not difficult.

It's also not hard to imagine coming up with a controller-type class that could connect to all your controls and whatnot to customize their appearance in some consistent, theme-like manner. Add an instance of that to each nib, connect all the controls, and let it do it's thing. You wouldn't see the effect until you actually run the app, of course, but it sounds like you're talking about customizing colors and fonts rather than size.

Comment: I understand that it's definitely possible to do this programmatically, (btw. is there something like NSThemeController?) but I was just wondering if there was any unknown limitation in why it is not somehow automated through IB.

Comment: Older versions of IB supported plugins for custom classes, but that has never been available for iOS views, and I don't think the IB that's built into Xcode 4 supports plugins at the moment. I'm sure a lot of people would like that. I doubt that there's any real technical limitation that would absolutely prevents such a thing, but implementing that would obviously mean not implementing something else. And no, there's no NSThemeController, but as I tried to say above, you could certainly write one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are at the mercy of the Almighty Apple Deity..... Bow at their feet and give thanks that you have what they give you..... lol...

Seriously tho. Apple puts in what apple wants and you can request additions, but the IB is fairly minimal in the way of features.

I think this may be by design. Somehow an Elegant Simplicity ?

The ability to customize the controls is given to the programmer however I think they want the controls standardized.  I just dont know why they didnt give a little more variety in the controls that are available. Like a few more button styles for the ios devices...

If you find out otherwise I would definitely be all ears.

Comment: Strangley though, I'd think if they wanted standardization they'd put as many style options in IB as possible, rather then encourage people to get crazy with programmatic styles, which I'd say are more likely to introduce graphical inconsistencies.

Or better yet, provide a concept of themes, and some way of getting a hold of some predefined 'Apple approved' ones.

Comment: but the iOS button only has one style. And it looks like garbage. Most commonly I am snagging a button image that looks just like a toolbar button, and stretching it as the background with my button type custom. Cause a white button with a 1px border... Umm No? I agree with them wanting to keep it consistent, but That seems like a bit of trouble to make it look "standard"

Comment: @DarkAngel - instead of doing that, why not spend a day and write a UIButton subclass that draws exactly how you want it to. Then you can use that class in all of your projects.

Comment: that is what I do. But it commonly has to do with setting the button style to custom and doing the image background as I want. Usually a stretch image that looks like other iOS buttons. Kind of a pain really

Answer (score 0):

I think that apple should let you to customize more the controls, for games it takes too much time to make the custom control ( you can make it faster in android as you can configure it in xml)

Btw PaintCode is another option to make your own style for components, it will generate the code but its more like interface builder

http://www.paintcodeapp.com/